# Swift Double convert to Int, the result is wrong

Tags: ios, swift3

First

```
let mDouble = 19.9 * 100.0 // 1990.0
let mInt = Int(mDouble) // the result is 1989
```

but

```
let mInt = Int(1990.0) // the result is 1990
```

so, how to get the right result?

Comment: Check similar questions like https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/4646572

Comment: Check the first line is returning '1989.9999999999998' not 1990.0, for which the integer is rounding off to 1989.

Comment: Try this :
        `let mInt = Int(round(mDouble))`